# "href:tel" link doesn't open alert view in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, extjs

I'm building a web app for different platforms based on Cordova platform and using ExtJS framework. Currently I'm trying to link phone numbers using the href="tel:0123456789" and it is working fine on Android and Window.

However when I tap on phone link in IOS,it does not display a default alert and initiates dialing without prompting.This is really strange, because even in Apple's URL Scheme Reference is said that:

> When a user taps a telephone link in a webpage, iOS displays an alert asking if the user really wants to dial the phone number and initiates dialing if the user accepts.

I tried:

•to remove an anchor tag in HTML and let the Safari automatically link phone numbers. -It did successfully anchored all of the numbers on the page, but yet again as soon as I tapped on them, it was calling straight away without alert confirmation.

•to use onclick="window.location.href = {phonenumber}" - The phone numbers didn't even got linked.

•to use 'telprompt' instead of 'tel' - 'telprompt' is no longer supported by Apple

I tested it on Iphone 6 and 5-same result.

So how can to make IOS display confirmation alert before calling in 'href=tel:' tags?

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

In html:

```
<a href="tel:1-xxx-xxx-xxxx">1-xxx-xxx-xxxx</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,but unfortunately it still calling without confirmation alert.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I got the solution...
Basically in addition to the answers from [HristoEftimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2765346/hristoeftimov) and [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172145/steve) I needed include `<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />` in my config.xml

However this breaks the code for Android so I have to implement it only for ios. So `<platform name="ios"><allow-intent href="tel:*" /><allow-navigation href="tel:*" /></platform>`

Moreover I had to call the tel link from onclick event: `<a onclick=" onPhoneNumberClick(' + arrayPhoneNumbers[i] + ')" href="javascript:void(0);">`

That called method onPhoneNumberClick, where I opened link in window.open like this:`window.open("tel:"+number);`